# Java generics extends and super implemented in collection and its subtypes

Tags: java, generics, collections, extend, covariance

I want to understand a bit more on java generics covariance and contravariance and how extends and super together work w.r.t collection and individual objects

```
class P1 {}

class P2 implements Collection<P2> { // implement collection methods }

class Base<T> {
transient List<T> _instList = new ArrayList<>();

protected Base(final List<T> list) {
    _instList = list;
}
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
class Emp<T> extends Base<Object> {

public <C extends Collection<T>> Emp(final List<? super C> list) {
    super((List<Object>) list);
}

public <C extends Collection<T>> void salary(C c) {

}

public <C extends Collection<? super T>> void credit(C c) {

}
}
```

In Main method,

```
1 Emp<P1> emp1 = new Emp<>(new ArrayList<P1>());// works, compiles fine
2 Emp<P2> emp2 = new Emp<>(new ArrayList<P2>());// works, compiles fine
3 emp1.credit(new P1()); // doesn't compile
4 emp2.credit(new P2()); // works
```

I want to understand how & why line 1 works when P1 is not a type of Collection

2 & 4 does compile, because P2 is a sub type of Collection.

Please clarify

Comment: when the line1 can compile, why not line2? In otherwords when line2 fails to compile how come it compiles line1?

Comment: Your example is missing details e.g. what is `Person`?

Comment: Corrected the question

Answer (score 0):

Line 1 matches the typebound of the constructor.

```
class Emp<P1> extends Base<Object> {

    public <C extends Collection<P1>> Emp(final List<? super C> list) {
        super((List<Object>) list);
    }
```

replacing T with P1 and C is ArrayList.
Nothing in that code requires P1 actually to implement Collection.

It is required to call credit(). Thats why you get an error in line3.